# Interpretation of interaction terms of continuous variables with quadratic regressors

Tags: regression, interaction

When estimating a regression with squared regressors and interaction effects, for instance: *Υ = β<sub>0</sub> + β<sub>1</sub>age + β<sub>2</sub>age<sup>2</sup> +
β<sub>3</sub>income + β<sub>4</sub>age*income + β<sub>5</sub>age<sup>2</sup>*income* , how would I interpret when β<sub>1</sub> is positive, β<sub>2</sub> is negative, β<sub>3</sub> is positive, β<sub>4</sub> is not significant and β<sub>5</sub> is negative?

I especially have a hard time interpreting the interaction effect of the quadradic effect. Could anyone explain this and possibly also know of a paper/book that discusses this? I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cant. And I think you already understand the intuition why. Namely, there are multiple things moving to have a "clean" interpretation of a single coefficient.

Consider the following. When you use a simple linear model, your specification would be:

$E(y|X)=a0+a1 * age + a2 * income$

This is just a linear approximation of the "true" function $E(y|X)=f(age,income)$.

Now, This model is easy to interpret, because the model assumes there are no interacting effects between age and income.

Once you start adding interactions, things change, and the effects are not isolated:

$E(y|x)=a0+a1*age+a2*income+a3*age*income$

In this case, a1 is the effect of age on $Y$ **only** if income=0. For other values, you need to take into account a3.

what if the model is:
$E(y|x)=a0+a1*age+a2*income+a3*age^2$

Again, a1 is the effect on Y only if age^2 =0. (so for someone who goes from age=0 to 1.)

Now, if you want to have a better sense of the interpretation, for a model like yours, you need to do one of two things:

1. Obtain the partial effects:

$\frac{\partial E(y|X)}{\partial age}= \beta_1 + 2 \beta_2 age +\beta_4 income + 2 \beta_5 age * income$

and substitute income and age for sensible values, or estimate this for everyone and take the average. These are the partial effects.

2. Modify your specification and obtain centered variables

Call $cage=age-E(age)$ and $cincome=income-E(income)$.

your model will now be:

$E(y|X)=β_0 + β_1 cage + β_2 cage^2 + β_3 cincome + β_4 cage*cincome + β_5 cage^2*cincome$

In this model the coefficients have a bit more of an explanation.
$\beta_1$: How y will increase if age increases if everything else is at its mean

$\beta_2$: If the effect is increasing or decreasing compared to the avg effect at the means

$\beta_4$: Interaction effect if BOTH age and income increase compare to their means.

$\beta_5$: How the increasing or decreasing effect changes as income changes (compared to the effect at the means).

HTH